# How to make a (MDX) calculation in a SSAS cube to get the difference between a value from the current row and a value from the previous row?

Tags: ssas, cube, dimension, calculation, measure

I would like to make a calculation to get the difference between the departDate from my current row and the arriveDateNextStop from my previous row. I have a fact table which has multiple columns. The three most important columns are: id, departDate, arriveDateNextStop.

If I have for example these two rows in my fact table:

- id    departDate arriveDateNextStop
- 1    01-01-2019 03-01-2019
- 1    04-01-2019 07-01-2019

Explanation: On 1 January 2019 I depart to the next destination and I arrive there on 3 January 2019. On 4 January 2019 I again depart to the next destination and I arrive there on 7 January 2019.

Now I would like to know how many days the idle time was (the amount of days between the arrival and the next depart). So with this example the idle time would be 1, because between 3 January 2019 and 4 January 2019 is one day.

First, I made this 'calculation' in Management Studio as a SQL query. See query below:

```
SELECT s.Id, s.departDate as Depart_current_place, s.arriveDateNextStop as Arrival_next_stop, LAG(arriveDateNextStop) OVER (ORDER BY arriveDateNextStop) AS Arrival_current_stop, DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG(arriveDateNextStop) OVER (ORDER BY arriveDateNextStop), departDate) AS Amount_of_days
FROM MyTable s
WHERE Id = 9
GROUP BY s.departDate, s.Id, s.arriveDateNextStop 
ORDER BY s.departDate
```

This query works fine, but how can I do this in my cube as a calculation in MDX?

Comment: You can add "Day Number" property (attribute w/o hierarchy) into your date dimension, this will be a day number from 1/1/1900 or any other year you prefer. And subtract this property (address it like .CurrentMember.Properties("Day Number")): current member - currentmember.prevmember. Split this measure into several simple measures: 1) day number of departure, 2) day number of arrival, 3) get previous day number of arrival, 4) subtraction in a final calculated measure. Update your question with the details you've done, and we'll resolve issues if they are.

Comment: @AlexPeshik But every simple measure needs another measure right? Because if I don't do that, everything will be null. I have in my cube measures from my factstable (and dimensions), but these measures doesn't make any sense.
I get what you are saying and it sounds good, but which measure do I need to use?

Comment: I'll try to create the similar example and let you know today (within several hours, I guess).

Comment: That would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the same example, but the similar cube structure with Completed/Received date:

```
with
member departDate as [Received].[Year Qtr Month].CurrentMember.Member_Key
member arriveDate as [Completed].[Year Qtr Month].CurrentMember.Member_Key
member arriveDateNextStop as [Completed].[Year Qtr Month].CurrentMember.Lead(1).Member_Key
member idleDays as departDate-arriveDateNextStop
 SELECT NON EMPTY { departDate,arriveDate,arriveDateNextStop,idleDays } ON 0
 , NON EMPTY
 { ([Completed].[Year Qtr Month].[Date].ALLMEMBERS
  * [Received].[Year Qtr Month].[Date].ALLMEMBERS ) }  ON 1 
 FROM ( SELECT ( { [Completed].[Year Qtr Month].[Date].&[6213] } ) ON COLUMNS
 FROM [MyCube])
```

I also have integer key for a date dimension (CurrentMember.Member_Key). 1 = 1998-01-01, 2 = 1998-01-02 etc. till today. You need to create a property in a Date dimension if your Date key is classic YYYYMMDD (which you cannot subtract to get days difference, I can do that in my example). And use it like CurrentMember.Properties("property name") instead of Member_Key.

Main formula part: Lag/Lead function to get prev. or next member.[image]

Please update in case of questions.

Comment: You have: .&[6213]. I think that is a standard value you put in (because the arriveDate is always 6213), but which value should I put there? And unfortunately I am not able to add columns to the time dimension (they told me to not change the structure)

Comment: Values 6213 was taken as an example, w/o filter it will work fine, I' just wanted to limit by one day to show dynamic difference calculation. If it's not allowed for you to add a column you can try to find VB function (MDX code can contain VB classic functions), and probably there is a function like DATEDIFF.